# xcode7 launchScreen.storyboard can not add image

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

in xcode7 ,launchscreen.storyboard could add label,textview... but can not add imageView in it. just couldn't display the image,how to solve?

Comment: What happens when you try to add a `UIImage view`? Is this in interface builder or in code?

Comment: Do you select proper size for the launchscreen?

Answer (score 0):

Double click the blank inside the viewcontroller to make sure the view zoom to 100%, and you will find you can insert imageview to the viewcontroller of the LaunchScreen.storyboard.

[click to show pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXcKV.png)